# How to get the value by different name in MYSQL

Tags: mysql

How to get the data with different field names in MYSQL?

I have a order table and columns as follows:

```
order_id, order_name
```

in results I want the field names as id and name like below:

```
{id: 1, name: "swamy"}
```

what's the best way to do this?

Comment: use alias => `order_name as name`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use `mysql alias` for the same.

```
SELECT
    order_id AS id
    order_name AS name
FROM order;
```

Answer (score 2):

Use SQL aliases like below

```
select  order_id AS id, order_name AS name from table_name;
```

For more ref: [SQL Aliases](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alias.asp)